# Get table from .aspx webpage to CSV file using C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a webpage ending with .aspx which contain a table. I want to know if there is any way to get that table into CSV file using C#? 
my html code is like this:

```
<div class="section_content">
    <div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped" cellspacing="0" id="gv_report">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Lot</th><th scope="col">Op</th><th scope="col">Status</th><th scope="col">iDispo Status</th><th scope="col">Dispo By</th><th scope="col">Dispo Date</th><th scope="col">T.R Count</th><th scope="col">View</th>
        </tr>
    </thead><tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>7649B703</td><td>6262</td><td>FAIL</td><td>FAIL</td><td>mly2</td><td>12/10/2016 4:30:47 PM</td><td>1</td><td>
                    <a href='/SS_PROD/Report/LotDispoHistSummRepPopUp.aspx?Lot=7649B703&Location=6262'
                        target="_blank"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>
                </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source file helpers to parse, convert and write different formatted files.

In you case you wanted to convert HTML table to CSV file. I'll show you sample code how to do it

For a sample HTML table

```
<table id="example1" border="1"  style="background-color:#FFFFCC" width="0%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mr.</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>07868785831</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Miss</td>
    <td>Linda</td>
    <td>0141-2244-5566</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Master</td>
    <td>Jack</td>
    <td>0142-1212-1234</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mr.</td>
    <td>Bush</td>
    <td>911-911-911</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm going to show how to grap Title, Name, Phone columns values and produce CSV file

```
using (var cr = new ChoCSVWriter("HtmlTable.csv").WithFirstLineHeader())
{
    using (var xr = new ChoXmlReader("HTMLTable.xml").WithXPath("/table/tr")
        .WithField("Title", xPath: "td[1]", fieldType: typeof(string))
        .WithField("Name", xPath: "td[2]", fieldType: typeof(string))
        .WithField("Phone", xPath: "td[3]", fieldType: typeof(string))
    )
    {
        cr.Write(xr.Where(r => !((string)r.Title).IsNullOrWhiteSpace()));
    }
}
```

In above, I've opened the XmlReader with column specs along with xpath to locate the individual fields. Then pass the reader to CSVWriter to create the CSV file

Here is the CSV output of the HTMLtable

```
Title,Name,Phone
Mr.,John,07868785831
Miss,Linda,0141-2244-5566
Master,Jack,0142-1212-1234
Mr.,Bush,911-911-911
```

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE:**

Your xml with few corrections to it

```
<div class="section_content">
  <div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped" cellspacing="0" id="gv_report">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Lot</th>
          <th scope="col">Op</th>
          <th scope="col">Status</th>
          <th scope="col">iDispo Status</th>
          <th scope="col">Dispo By</th>
          <th scope="col">Dispo Date</th>
          <th scope="col">T.R Count</th>
          <th scope="col">View</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>7649B703</td>
          <td>6262</td>
          <td>FAIL</td>
          <td>FAIL</td>
          <td>mly2</td>
          <td>12/10/2016 4:30:47 PM</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>
            <a href='/SS_PROD/Report/LotDispoHistSummRepPopUp.aspx?Lot=7649B703&Location=6262' target="_blank">
              <i class="icon-eye-open"></i>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7649B703</td>
          <td>6262</td>
          <td>FAIL</td>
          <td>FAIL</td>
          <td>mly2</td>
          <td>12/10/2016 4:30:47 PM</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>
            <a href='/SS_PROD/Report/LotDispoHistSummRepPopUp.aspx?Lot=7649B703&Location=6262' target="_blank">
              <i class="icon-eye-open"></i>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code to convert them to CSV file

```
using (var cr = new ChoCSVWriter("HtmlTable.csv").WithFirstLineHeader())
{
    using (var xr = new ChoXmlReader("HTMLTable.xml").WithXPath("//tbody/tr")
        .WithField("Lot", xPath: "td[1]", fieldType: typeof(int))
        .WithField("Op", xPath: "td[2]", fieldType: typeof(int))
        .WithField("Status", xPath: "td[3]", fieldType: typeof(string))
        .WithField("iDispoStatus", xPath: "td[4]", fieldType: typeof(string))
        .WithField("DispoBy", xPath: "td[5]", fieldType: typeof(string))
        .WithField("DispoDate", xPath: "td[6]", fieldType: typeof(DateTime))
        .WithField("TRCount", xPath: "td[7]", fieldType: typeof(int))
        .WithField("View", xPath: "td[8]/a/@href", fieldType: typeof(string))
    )
    {
        cr.Write(xr);
    }
}
```

CSV Output:

```
Lot,Op,Status,iDispoStatus,DispoBy,DispoDate,TRCount,View
0,6262,FAIL,FAIL,mly2,12/10/2016,1,/SS_PROD/Report/LotDispoHistSummRepPopUp.aspx?Lot=7649B70
0,6262,FAIL,FAIL,mly2,12/10/2016,1,/SS_PROD/Report/LotDispoHistSummRepPopUp.aspx?Lot=7649B703
```

Comment: Yes, the pattern is like that. I just want to extract the header and data from it

Comment: Your xml is failing to load with error at '<a href='/SS_PROD/Report/LotDispoHistSummRepPopUp.aspx?Lot=7649B703&Location=6262' target="_blank">' line. Clean it up and successfully converted. See my update above.